# How to make wireless working on HP Pavilion g6-2220?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, hp

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion g6-2220 as only OS. I have tried several ways, but still can't get my computer to understand the Wi-Fi button on/or even acknowledge it is there. Wired Internet works great, but the wireless will not function at all.

Any help on how to get my wireless up and running?

Comment: Please run lspci -nn and post the details of your wireless card.

Answer (score 1):

Install synaptic from Ubuntu software center.

select and install **bcmwl-kernel-source** and **bcmwl-sta-source** . That should  install the Broadcom STA wireless driver. Hope it works!! :)